# Copy Lookup reference to another list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

So i have 2 lists, a and b. some of the fields in list a such as envelope (dropdown) is based on a lookup reference. I'd like to create a workflow wherein if envelope 001 has been chosen, envelope 001 from the reference table will not be available anymore in the option. is there a way to. do this?

or can I create a rule wherein if envelope 001 is chosen, envelope 001 in the reference table will be transferred to list b?

Comment: Please take a look at the below Answer and mark it as a solution if it works for you. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**There is a way to do this, but you will need to utilize a workflow.**

- Create List 2 with Title as the values for List 1 lookup
- Create column in list 1 that looks up to the title column of list 2
- Create workflow on list 1 for edit/create trigger (reference
  screenshots below)
- Grab the drop down value and store in a variable PLAIN TEXT
- Then using that variable, get List 2 item from Title column and
  Delete (screenshots)
- When item edited on list 1 it will lookup and delete an item from list 2
- Now on list 1, only the remaining items will be available.

**Let me know if the below images explain this clearly enough**

---

**THIS IS THE WORKFLOW THAT SITS ON LIST 1**
[image: This is the workflow on List 1]
[image: VALUES ON LIST 2 IN TITLE COLUMN]

[image]
**THIS IS THE NEW ITEM ON LIST 1**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: Glad to help! 